# How to control the brightness of an LED with or without additional hardware by setting a variable

Tags: gpio, python, led

I already know that using for example `GPIO.output(led_pin, led_state)` I can turn on and off an LED.

What I would like to have, is to adjust the brightness of an LED, either by an absolute value (in whatever measurement unit) or by a percentage. Something like `led_brightness(led_pin, 50) # 50% brightness`.

Comment: Have you looked into the PWM class? [Some examples here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/98884/RPi.GPIO.PWM)

Comment: I actually did but I didn't know what the values of the variables were in those examples.

Comment: Mentioning that might have made a better question?

Comment: How? Because I didn't take wild guesses what the value of a variable is, which I never saw being initialized or any value assigned to it? All the other cases ware usage of booleans.

Comment: To let us know what you've tried. This is covered under the ["How to ask a good question" topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gpiozero library allows led brightness using pulse-width-modulation:

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#led-with-variable-brightness

Answer (score 1):

pigpio lets you use hardware timed PWM to change LED brightness.

The default frequency is 800 Hz which will be fine for LEDs (you can change the frequency with [set_PWM_frequency](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_frequency)).

To change the LED brightness change the PWM dutycycle with [set_PWM_dutycycle](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_dutycycle) between 0 (off) to 255 (fully on).

As hardware timing is used the LED will not occasionally noticeably glitch as fully on or off.